# Would this be a valid proof for triangle inequality?

Tags: solution-verification, triangle-inequality

I am a first year Mathematics student. I have this homework where I have to prove the reverse triangle inequality $(||x|-|y|| ≤ |x-y| )$. I have proven it with the triangle inequality, so I had to include the proof of triangle inequality as well. So I proved it too, but I found no proof like mine, so I am a little paranoid about my proof. I wanted to ask you people about it. The proof:

Let a and b be real numbers.

- Since $a ≤ |a|$ and $b ≤ |b|$, we can get the sum of both inequations. So, $a + b ≤ |a| + |b|$
- And similarly $-a ≤ |-a| = |a|$ and $-b ≤ |-b| = |b|$. So, $(-a) + (-b) ≤ |a| + |b|$ which implies that $-(a + b) ≤ |a| + |b|$.
- Hence, since both $a + b ≤ |a| + |b|$ and $-(a + b) ≤ |a| + |b|$ are true, $|a + b| ≤ |a| + |b|$ is also true as desired. QED

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: In your second bullet point your third = should be $\le$. Apart from that the argument is correct. It's also a fairly standard argument, not clear why you needed to ask here.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad there I mistyped there. As I've said I was a little paranoid about my proof since it looked a lot more clear to me than other proofs that I looked up on the internet. Thank you so much for your help @SuzuHirose

Comment: @helvacitaha we all get a little anxious about proofs at first but there will come a point when you have to trust yourself. If you're right, you'll know.